# Unable to uninstall brew php from homebrew

Tags: php, homebrew

I am trying to uninstall php@7.2 using homebrew but it keeps on saying
    Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.2
how to uninstall it and what is keg?

Answer (score 3):

Had the same error (OS Mojave 10.14) with local php 7.1 needing for update. Issue was when trying to install PHP version with homebrew the installation didn't work because of a `curl` error - solution was to use brewed `curl` instead of system `curl`

Initially tried:

```
brew install shivammathur/php/php@7.4
```

Reponse was:

```
Error: Failed to download resource "freetds"
```

used the following command to update the errored package `freetds` myself:

```
HOMEBREW_FORCE_BREWED_CURL=1 brew install freetds
```

After this ran the homebrew php command again (update took very long):

```
brew install shivammathur/php/php@7.4
```

Then forced the php7.4 version

```
 brew link --overwrite --force shivammathur/php/php@7.4
```

And then

```
php -v
```

And succcess:

```
PHP 7.4.28 (cli) (built: Apr  3 2022 20:51:36) ( NTS )
```

Hope this saves someone a day!

Answer found here: [reference](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/1752#discussioncomment-935765)

Answer (score 0):

Keg is the term homebrew uses for a package (AFAIK, the terms confuse me a lot still).

So it means there is no package found called php@7.2. Are you sure that is the version you have installed. It might just be called [`php`](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/php).

You can run `brew list` to find all installed packages and look for one the looks like it could be the `php` package you are trying to uninstall.